# Basic induction proof that all natural numbers can be written in the form $2a + 3b$

Tags: proof-writing, induction

The theorem given is:

> If $n$ is a natural number then $n$ can be written in the form $2a + 3b$ for some integers $a$ and $b$.

How would I prove this by induction? I've had a go at proving this but I don't know if my technique is sound.

The base case would be when n = 1 = 2(-1) + 3(1) (if we take the natural numbers as excluding 0). Then if I assume n = 2a + 3b is true, n+1=2a+3b+1. Therefore n+1=2a+3b+2(-1)+3(1) which can be written as n+1=2(a-1)+3(b+1) which should conclude the proof.

Is this a proper proof or is there some other way of doing it? How would I prove the theorem if I took the natural numbers to include 0 (i.e. could I still use 1=2(-1)+3(1) when it would no longer be the base case)?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hint: 1 = 3 - 2. Your proof won't be by induction if you use this, though.

Comment: @Magdiragdag, that is a *most* unhelpful comment.

Comment: @dfeuer Is it? I could have commented that gcd(2,3) = 1, but considered that to be confusing for a hint.

Comment: @Magdiragdag, the OP had already demonstrated that they knew what to do with that fact!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof is perfectly good. You can use whatever integer $b$ you like as the base case, to prove some proposition $P(n)$ is true for all integers $n\ge b$. $0$ and $1$ are both very common base cases. You can also use induction in the other direction (e.g., for negative numbers) to prove that every integer *below* $b$ satisfies the proposition.

Formally, induction is usually defined in the upwards direction, and usually to start at $0$ (or $1$, depending which text you use), but extending it to do other things is quite straightforward. The downward induction can be recast as upwards: rather than induction downward in $n$, do induction upward in $-n$. Same thing.

Comment: Thanks! What you said about using induction in the other direction is really interesting and helpful; I hadn't thought about doing that.

Comment: @FalseAzure, the integers are very nice: you can split them at the point of your choice to get one set that looks a lot like the natural numbers and one set that looks a lot like the natural numbers turned around backwards. In (most?) more general inductive contexts (structural induction, transfinite induction, and wellfounded induction), only the upwards way makes sense.

Comment: Of course, $n=0$ would be the "nicer" base case as you simply have $0=2\cdot 0+3\cdot 0$. :)

Answer (score 1):

Also  you can avoid induction. For instance if $n$ is even then $n=2\cdot a+3\cdot 0.$ If n is odd then $n=2\cdot a+1$ for some natural $a.$ Further, $1=3-2$ so 
$n=2a+3-2=2\cdot (a-1)+3\cdot 1.$